# Correct way to style a section of a material-ui document

Tags: material-ui

I have a header and want to style all of it's buttons differently than my global theme. I have tried using a child theme like:

```
    <ThemeProvider
      theme={(outerTheme) =>
        _.merge(outerTheme, {
          overrides: {
            MuiButton: {
              label: {
                color: "#fff",
              },
            },
          },
        })
      }
    >
```

However, while I had expected this to override only `MuiButton`'s in the child theme, it overrode them in them globally.

I know I can use `makeStyles` but, then, as far as I know, I have to reference it in all the child components which want to use the style. I'd like to wrap a higher level component and have all child components pick up the style. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { purple } from '@material-ui/core/colors';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  header: {
    "& button": {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
      color: theme.palette.getContrastText(purple[500]),
      backgroundColor: purple[500],
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: purple[700],
      },
    },
  },
});

function CustomHeader(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
 
  return (
    <div className={classes.header}>
      <Button>Button 1</Button>
      <Button>Button 2</Button>
      <Button disabled>Button 3</Button>
    </div>
  ) 
};
```